# What does the 1000 candy option do in the game in the locked house?

Tags: candy-box-2

Been playing this game for a while now, but haven't done the option of 1000 candies in the game in the house that used to be locked. I don't want to waste one thousand candies. Can anybody tell me what it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Paying 1,000 candies activates the game Galactic Wars.

http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/The_third_house_in_the_village